# Proof: If $ A \iota_N=0\Rightarrow A^{+'}\iota_N=0$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

I want to show that if $ A \iota_N=0\Rightarrow A^{+'}\iota_N=0$ where $A^+$ is the Pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** $A^+=A^+AA^+$ and $A^+A=(A^+A)^T$ give $A^+=(A^+A)^TA^+=A^T(A^+)^TA^+$, so $(A^+)^T=[A^T(A^+)^TA^+]^T=(A^+)^TA^+A.$

Answer (score 0):

So, it must be
\begin{align}
(A^+)'\iota_N&=(A^+AA^+)'\iota_N\\
&=((A^+A)'A^+)'\iota_N\\
&=(A'(A^+)'A^+)'\iota_N\\
&=(A^+)'A^+)'A\iota_N\\
&=(A^+)'A^+)'0\\
&=0.
\end{align}